# Organizing web api URLs in MVC web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm fixing up an mvc web front end that uses an existing web api for data.
There are 7 or 8 different URLs for the web api calls, peppered through out the controllers.

I plan to replace the strings with variables, and I would like to have a central place to configure this, so once I put the web api back on the server, I just have to change the URL variables in one place, instead of search through the controllers.

Is there a convention for this already? If not, would the web config be the best spot?

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would create a proxy class for working with the web API. This would give you a place to centralize the URIs and hide the details (like dealing with http, authentication, serialization, etc.) of working with the API directly.

```
class SomeApi {
  // or read this from config
  const string baseUrl = "https://some-site/api";

  public Task<Customer> GetCustomerAsync(int customerId) {
    // implement me
  }
}

// consumers don't have to know anything about urls, http, etc.
var api = new SomeApi();
var customer = await GetCustomerAsync(1234);
```